# Separating files based on file extension?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I want to separate the files in my models based on extension type. Right now I am able to print all the files but now I want to separate them based on extension and apply separate functions based on the extensions.

**The code in my models.py**

```
class File(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    doc = models.FileField(upload_to='files/docs/', validators=[FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['pdf','docx'])])`
```

**and my code in view.py**

```
def file_p():

    for file in File.objects.all():
        print(file.doc)
```

**I am getting an output something like this:**

```
files/docs/12.6.1-packet-tracer---troubleshooting-challenge---document-the-network_1s00TUA.docx
files/docs/12.6.1-packet-tracer---troubleshooting-challenge---document-the-network_z9b2tyh.pdf
```

How can I separate them based on the extension so that I can apply further functions based on the file type?

Answer (score 0):

You can make this using custom Model functions.
**models.py**

```py
class File(modles.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    doc = models.FileField(upload_to='files/docs/', validators=[FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['pdf','docx'])])
 
    def doc_pdf(self):
        name, extension = os.path.splitext(self.doc.name)
        if 'pdf' in extension:
            return self.doc
    def doc_docx(self):
        name, extension = os.path.splitext(self.doc.name)
        if 'docx' in extension:
            return self.doc
```

**views.py**

```py
def file_p():
    for file in File.objects.all():
        #get pdf files
        print(file.doc_pdf)
        #get docx files
        print(file.doc_docx)
```

Comment: Thank you so much it worked. Can you help me with another thing? I want to be able to check for certain words in the files so that if the files contain such words it will not be send? Is it possible? If so how can i do that?

Comment: Yeah, Is that possible. [read this article](https://www.codespeedy.com/check-if-a-string-exists-in-a-pdf-file-in-python/) and pls accept my answer if it works.

Comment: One question do i try this method in the model function or in the views function?